# How to flash session data when redirect to intended() using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, web, session

I'm trying to redirect to the intended URL after login, and flash some session data together to show a popup modal only once.

If I do this, it works:

```php
return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with('showWelcome', true);
```

I can retrieve the session in blade view as such:

```php
@if (session('showWelcome'))
    // show modal..
@endif
```

However, if I use `intended()`, the session is no way to be found:

```php
return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with('showWelcome', true);
```

I've also tried the following:

- using the following instead of `with()`:

```php
$request->session()->flash('showWelcome', true);
```

- using the `\Session` Class instead of the `session()` helper to retrieve the session data:

```php
@if (\Session::has('showWelcome'))
    // show modal
@endif
```

Unfortunately, the problem persists where it only works when I'm **not** using `intended()`.

I've searched high and low but couldn't exactly find any solution to this.

Am I doing something wrong or understanding how redirect works incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the flash message, so you may try something like this to achieve the same function
**store data**

```
$request->session()->put('showWelcome', true);
return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
```

**retrieve data**

```
$showWelcome = $request->session()->pull('showWelcome');
```

Hope that works!

Comment: Yes using `put()` and `pull()` works. Thanks!